# UILabel animate the width

Tags: ios

How do we go about animating the `UILabel`'s width so that it increases and decreases in width only using `UIView` `animateWithDuration`

Thank you for your help (at this point i'm so frustrated as I've been trying to do so but it does not work)

Comment: Share what you tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it in this way. self refers to the view in which i'm adding the label. in the init, add the label with width as 1 px. then use the below.. the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState allows it to be opened like a door PHEW!

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1. delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState  animations:^{
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x-labelSize.width-PADDING, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width+labelSize.width+PADDING, self.frame.size.height)];
        [self.messageLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(95, 10, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
        self.messageLabel.alpha = 1; 
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1. delay:2. options:0  animations:^{
            self.messageLabel.alpha = 0;  
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1. delay:0. options:0  animations:^{
                [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x+labelSize.width+PADDING, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width-labelSize.width-PADDING, self.frame.size.height)];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the frame of the `UILabel` inside the UIView animation block. Something like this:

```
CGRect originalFrame = self.address.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
    self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // use similar UIView animation to resize back to original
                 }];
```

Obviously the dimensions you feed in will depend on your app, and may be calculated based on the content.

Comment: how to open it and then shorten it again?

Comment: tried this but this just makes the label disappear, not close shut at the end of animation          [UIView animateWithDuration:1. delay:1. options:0 animations:^{
            [self.messageLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 100, 90)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:2. animations:^{
                [self.messageLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 0, 90)];
            }];
        }];

Comment: That's the approach I would take (I've updated my answer to include those details). Your final animation finishes with a height of zero so it wont be visible, I would have though it would animate though

Comment: tried this (same as the above answer) the label snaps back to the old frame and does not animate into it

Answer (score 0):

try to increase and decrease the frame width with an animation as below

```
    // original label frame CGRectMake( 0,0, 100,60 );
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"moveLogo" context: nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4];
    //increasing frame width
    label.frame =  CGRectMake( 0,0, 400,60 );   
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^(void)
  {
     self.label.bounds = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100); 

 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^(void)
     {
         self.label.bounds = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100); 
     }];

 }];
```

Comment: at the end of the animation, the label frame just snaps to the old frame and does not animate into the old frame

Answer (score 0):

finally did it like this with blocks in iOS 5.0

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2. delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState  animations:^{
            [self.messageLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, labelSize.width, 90)];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```